# Supported chipset for monitor mode and packet injection in kali Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, network-interface, realtek

I want to buy wifi adaptor/chipset which supported monitor mode and packet injection in Kali Linux.

(Personally tested)Can anyone currently used any adepter for same ? Also share chipset(except Atheros chipset) which supported above functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Monitor Mode Supported WiFi Chipset/Adapter List :**

**Atheros Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• Atheros AR5000

• Atheros AR5001A-AR5007EG

• Atheros AR5000-AR5007EG

• Atheros AR5005U (AR5523)

• Atheros AR9001U (AR9170)

• Atheros AR2427+AR5008+AR900x

• Atheros AR9002U (AR9271, AR7010)

**Broadcom Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• Broadcom BCM4301, BCM4307, BCM4306r2

• Broadcom BCM4306r3, BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4309, BCM4318(E), BCM4321, BCM4322

• Broadcom BCM43224, BCM43225, BCM4331

• Broadcom BCM43224, BCM43225

**Intel Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• Intel PRO/Wireless 2100B

• Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG

• Intel Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN

• Intel WiFi Link 5100, 5150, 5300, 5350 - Centrino 100, 130, 1000, 1030, 6150, 6200, 6250, 6300

**Intersil Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• Intersil PRISM 2/2.5/3 PCI/CF/PCMCIA

• Intersil PRISM 2.5/3 USB

• Intersil ISL3877, ISL3880,ISL3890, ISL3886

• Intersil ISL3880/ISL3886 + NET2280, ISL3887

**Ralink Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• Ralink RT2460

• Ralink RT2560

• Ralink RT2561, RT2561S, RT2661

• Ralink RT2571, RT2572

• Ralink RT2571W, RT2573, RT2671

• Ralink RT2760, RT2790, RT2860, RT2880,

• Ralink RT2890, RT3052, RT3090, RT3091, RT3092, RT3390,RT3060, RT3062, RT3562, RT3592, RT5390, RT3290

• Ralink RT2760, RT2790, RT2860, RT2880, RT2890, RT3052, RT309x

• Ralink RT2770, RT2870, RT2070, RT3070, RT3071, RT3072, RT3370, RT3572, RT5370, RT5572,RT8070

**Realtek Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• Realtek RTL8180L, RTL8185L, RTL8187SE (3.15+)
• Realtek RTL8187L, RTL8187B
• Realtek RTL8188SU, RTL8191SU, RTL8192SU
• Realtek RTL8188CUS, RTL8192CU, RTL8188RU

**Texas Instruments Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• Texas Instruments ACX100 (TNETW1100), ACX101 (TNETW1100B), ACX111 (TNETW1130), TNETW1450

• Texas Instruments WL1251

**ZyDAS Chipset List with monitor mode support**

• ZyDAS ZD1201

• ZyDAS ZD1211/ZD1211B

More information : [Best Kali Linux Wifi Adapter](https://wifivisit.blogspot.com/2019/08/best-kali-linux-compatible-wifi-adapter-under-rs-1000-in-2019-india.html)

Answer (score 2):

For now the best is

- Realtek RTL8814AU
- Atheros AR9271
- Realtek RTL8812AU 5ghz

however you can check for the best supported adapter at this website
https://kalitut.com/usb-wi-fi-adapters-supporting-monitor/

Comment: RT5370 chipset is cheapest across those;